# Which description for Nagle algorithm is correct?

Tags: c, linux, tcp, linux-kernel

The following are two simple descriptions for Nagle algorithm.

> Version 1: Wait for the peer to acknowledge the previously sent packets before sending any partial packets
>
> Version 2: Wait for the peer to acknowledge the previously sent **partial** packets before sending any partial packets

Version 1 is the result of what I understand from the googled info, such as [Wiki(Nagle's algorithm)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nagle%27s_algorithm) or [TCP_CORK: More than you ever wanted to know](http://baus.net/on-tcp_cork)

Version 2 is the result of what I understand from the Linux kernel implementation of Nagle's algorithm

```
static inline int tcp_nagle_check(const struct tcp_sock *tp,
                              const struct sk_buff *skb,
                              unsigned mss_now, int nonagle)
{
    return (skb->len < mss_now &&
            ((nonagle & TCP_NAGLE_CORK) ||
             (!nonagle && tp->packets_out && tcp_minshall_check(tp))));
}
```

The function tcp_minshall_check() checks whether all sent small packets are ACKed.

So my questions are:

1. Which of the description is correct?
2. If both are correct, what is the advantages of the Linux's modification?

Comment: whichever is correct, there's no such thing as a "partial packet" in TCP.

Comment: I guess "partial packet" means packets with length smaller than MSS. Why it does not exsit in TCP?

Comment: because TCP is a stream-orientated protocol, and the underlying _segmentation_ is supposed to be invisible to the application layer.  Each TCP packet is _by definition_ complete (unless it has suffered IP layer _fragmentation_).

Comment: Read the source - http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc896

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only difference between these two, as you have written them down, is that (2) will send one partial segment without delay even if there are unacked segments, if those segments are full size. I.e. if it has been recently sending only full sized segments and some of them are still "in the air".

This is a good thing because that situation does not indicate a chatty connection that uses small packets. That situation occurs frequently at the end of a bulk transfer of data. Unless the size of a file transfer is divisible exactly by the size of a TCP segment so that the last piece fills a segment, which is an unlikely occurrence, a data burst will have an incomplete segment as its last piece.

There is no point in delaying the sending of the last piece of a bulk transfer just because it is smaller.

Rule 1 will slow down nearly every HTTP transfer by causing the sender to implement a pointless delay before sending the last piece.

(Are you sure that's the real rule? Pay attention to Nikolai N Fetissov's comment be sure to read the real RFC rather than second hand sources.)